# Cannot solve this integral used in quantum chemistry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, quantum-field-theory, chemistry, quantum-calculus

I am writing computer code for an implementation of the Hartree Fock algorithm and I am stuck on a certain integral. This is a great walkthrough to get some background : [HFTheory](http://ronispc.chem.mcgill.ca/ronis/chem345/hartree-fock.pdf)

Anyway, the set-up is this. I am using a single Guassian type orbital as my basis function for an approximation to helium. This is defined (in cartesian coordinates) by

$$\displaystyle \phi_2(x,y,z) = ne^{-a(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}$$

And I want to plug that into the following

$$U_\mathrm{eff}(1)= \int \mathrm{d}(2)\,\frac{\left|\phi_2(x,y,z)\right|^2}{r_{12}}$$ 
This leads to something like so
$$U_\mathrm{eff}(1)= \int \int \int \frac{\left|\phi_2(x,y,z)\right|^2}{r_{12}} dx dydz$$
$$U_\mathrm{eff}(1)= \int \int \int \frac{\left|ne^{-a(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}\right|^2}{r_{12}} dx dydz$$
Now $r_{12}$ is the distance between the nuclei so this is just $\left|r_1 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|$ so plugging this in I get 
$$U_\mathrm{eff}(1)= \int \int \int \frac{\left|ne^{-a(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}\right|^2}{\left|r_1 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|} dx dydz$$

I've plugged this into many a program and it seems like it is unsolvable, any ideas?

Comment: you are working with nuclei…are they spheric by any chance? (are your bounds in spherical coordinates?)

Comment: Yeah good call, maybe you can simplify this in spherical coordinates, but still if an integral can be solved in spherical it can be solved in cartesian right? So this should still be solvable.

Comment: no not necessarily, for example $\iint e^{x^2+y^2}dxdy$ is  trivial in polar coordinates but very hard if not impossible in cartesian. Since your function has terms in $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2$ I would definitely try it in spherical coordinates.

Comment: The formula for $r_{12}$ looks wrong. What is $(x,y,z)$, location of what?

Comment: @Kuifje could you maybe give some hints on how to do that... sorry haven't looked at integrals since high school :)

Comment: @achillehui Well $r_1$ is the location of electron 1 and same for $r_2$ so I was thinking by vector subtraction the distance between the two vectors is $r_1 - r_2$, and in cartesian coordinates that would be the formula above

Comment: Before dealing with computing issues I would check the comment from @achillehui…I think he is right, are you sure your model is correct?

Comment: Try looking in Jackson for the 1/r12 expansion in Legendre. If the Gaussian is highly peaked you can make a useful approximation.

Comment: @Kuifje does that explanation make sense? If not what do you think the formula for $r_{12}$ should be?

Comment: the distance between two electrons $i=1,2$ at positions $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ would be $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$

Comment: @Kuifje yeah you are right but that integral is even more complicated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the coordinate axes and introduce polar coordinates such that

- the $1^{st}$ electron is located at $\vec{p}_1 = (0,0,r_1)$.
- the $2^{nd}$ electron is located at $\vec{p}_2 = (x,y,z) = (r \sin\theta\cos\phi, r \sin\theta\sin\phi, r\cos\theta)$

It is known that $\frac{1}{r_{12}} = \frac{1}{|\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_2|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(r_1-z)^2}}$ has
following [Multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion)
(see $\S 3.3$ of Classical Electrodynamics by J.D.Jackson ).
$$\frac{1}{r_{12}} = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{r_<^{\ell}}{r_>^{\ell+1}}P_\ell(\cos\theta)$$
where $r_< = \min(r_1, r)$, $r_> = \max(r_1,r)$ and $P_\ell(t)$ is the 
[Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) of degree $\ell$.

The sort of integral you want to calculate can be expressed as

$$\int \frac{e^{-\beta r^2}}{r_{12}} d^3\vec{p}_2
= \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-\beta r^2} \frac{r_<^\ell}{r_>^{\ell+1}} r^2 dr \right)\left(\int_0^{\pi} P_\ell(\cos\theta) \sin\theta d\theta \right)\left(\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\right)\tag{*1}$$

The key is

$$\int_0^{\pi} P_\ell(\cos\theta) \sin\theta d\theta 
= \int_{-1}^{1} P_\ell(t) dt  = 
\begin{cases}
2, &\ell = 0,\\
0, &\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
and we only need to keep the $\ell = 0$ term in $(*1)$. As a result,
$$\int \frac{e^{-\beta r^2}}{r_{12}} d^3\vec{p}_2
= 4\pi \int_0^\infty e^{-\beta r^2} \frac{r^2}{r_>} dr
= 4\pi \left(\int_0^{r_1} e^{-\beta r^2} \frac{r^2}{r_1} dr 
+ \int_{r_1}^\infty e^{-\beta r^2} r dr \right)
$$
I will leave the rest of computation to you.